# May I earn Aeroflot or Air France miles flying with China Eastern?

Tags: loyalty-programs, air-france, aeroflot, skyteam, china-eastern

China Eastern, Air France and Aeroflot belong to the SkyTeam alliance. I'm a frequent flyer in Air France and Aeroflot and now I'm going to purchase a China Eastern flight. May I earn miles with any of the loyalty programs I'm already working with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Flying Blue you will earn level miles and award miles, and the flight will count as a qualifying flight, but only if your flight is *not* booked into the Z, Q or G booking codes.

https://www.flyingblue.com/earn-and-spend-miles/airlines/partner/180/china-eastern.html

The usual exceptions apply.

As a frequent flier, your usual SkyPriority benefits will apply on China Eastern, provided your Air France or Aeroflot number is in the booking.

[Note, that you will probably earn more miles if you book the flight under an AF or KL codeshare, as this will accrue at the AF or KL rate not at the MU rate.]

Answer (score 6):

The definitive guide on where you can credit miles to and how much you will earn is on [wheretocredit](http://www.wheretocredit.com/china-eastern-airlines). From that, you can see the earning rates on Flying Blue and Aeroflot.

*Where to Credit* provides mileage earning calculations for frequent flyer programs around the world. The site is not affiliated with airlines (nor do I have any connection to it) and the site owners accept updates by users if any mistakes are found.

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: While the link you provide is helpful and answers the OP's question, it's good in general to include a summary of the page you link to so your answer remains useful even if the link becomes broken later.

Comment: @davidvc Noted. Updated.